# How do I JUST replace text in a file (Like all of the text)

Tags: batch-file, text

I've been searching for a while now and Google's terrible algorithm gives me everything but the aching question I've been asking. I'm trying to create a sort of password lock script, and I'm trying to create a lock out function. Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off

set tries=3

:type
set /p mytextfile=< zepassword.txt
if %mytextfile%==LOCKED goto locked

echo Please type in your key.
set /p okay=
if %okay%==yes goto good
if not %okay%==yes goto bad


:good 
cls
echo Correct Password.
pause >nul
exit

:bad 
cls
set /a tries=%tries%-1
echo This key is incorrect. %tries% tries remaining.
pause >nul
if %tries%==0 echo LOCKED >> zepassword.txt
goto type

:locked
cls
echo You are LOCKED OUT.
echo Press any key to unlock.
pause >nul
echo UNLOCKED >> zepassword.txt
pause >nul
```

Comment: You aren't finding anything because your question is unclear. What do you mean by "replace all of the text in a file?" Are you trying to delete the contents of a file and write new data to it? If so, just change `>>` to `>`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that earlier but it didn't work. It works now, and I think it was because I had the file hidden lol

Comment: Sure would love to know what you were searching for on Google and StackOverflow because there are dozens of questions here about creating and writing to files.

Comment: @Squashman - probably searching for "replace" instead of "overwrite"

Comment: FYI in the future, there's no need to explain how and where you searched, or speculate on a search engine's algorithm. It just adds unneeded clutter to a question.

Answer (score 0):

SomethingDark answered this question for me.

echo text > [File name]